# Is it professional to ask when my converted leave credits will be given?

Tags: professionalism, benefits, leave

I’ve been working for a company (a startup) for 13 months. My contract states that I have 5 days of sick leave and 5 days of vacation leave, but it doesn’t state anything about *when* the converted amount will be given if unused. Both the sick and vacation leaves were actually unused, so I thought it will be paid to me together with my 13th month pay (mandated by law to be given before Dec 24, which I had to remind to my boss also). It didn’t happen, though.

Would it be professional to ask my boss when my converted leave credits will be given? I’m about to quit this job in February or March, so if ever, would that be a better time to mention the unused leaves?

Comment: Asking work-related questions is professional as soon as you formulate it professionaly. Do you have any other point of contact than your boss ? Do you have any colleagues with whom you might discuss this point ? Is there an HR departement you could ask ? Anyway, any request you might have will probably be better done before you announce you're leaving as it easier to get things from actual colleagues/employer than from a former one (or soon to be)

Comment: Can you please include a jurisdiction?

Comment: @LaurentS. The company unfortunately doesn't have an HR department, and I'm stuck with asking it directly to my boss. Also, my boss already knows that I'm leaving but requested me to move my last day of work until we find a replacement that I'll train. Anyway, I'll make sure the converted credits will be given before my exit.

Comment: @mkennedy Could you clarify what you meant with "jurisdiction"?

Comment: What country is this? Thanks!

Comment: @mkennedy The Philippines.

Answer (score 1):

The discussion of legal or contractual terms are always acceptable discussions, as long they are civil and professionally held.

It is the way they are mentioned that makes it unprofessional.  E.g. whining, demanding, etc.

Comment: I’m aware that whining or demanding is a big no-no, but I doubt that my words might not be the apt for the situation, thus it may come across with the incorrect message. How can I mention it without sounding demanding?

Comment: The simplest method is to ask questions.  "Do you know how long it takes for my leave and sick days to be reimbursed as pay?"

Comment: It's very hard to ask real questions and have it be demanding.  You can still do that by asking rethorical questions, but I would argue you're no longer asking a real question at that point.

Comment: I was initially thinking of starting it off saying that “my contract indicates sick and vacation leave but I didn’t see any clause about the time reimbursement will be given, so I want to verify”, but maybe I could also include your question on the last part of mine.